How to set Environmental variables in Zoho Catalyst?
I want to set Environment variable in Catalyst. I'm using Node js where i want to set the env variable.

You can set the Environment variable in both Development and Production environment from the Catalyst console. To set up an environment variable in Development environment for the Catalyst functions, you can navigate to Catalyst Console->{Your_Project}->Serverless->Functions->{Your_functions}->Configuration->Environment Variables.
You can declare the environment variable as a key-value pair. You can find the help documentation for the same here.
Also, you can set the Environment variable in the catalyst-config.json which you can find in the Catalyst functions.
